# Как прочитать строку URL?

Tags: php

Например пользователь ввел строку типа `http://example.com/page/ehdfngdfbgf`

Вопрос. Как определить что ввел пользователь? (`ehdfngdfbgf`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

С помощь **$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']** определяете  то что находиться в строке браузера, в вашем случае это будет **page/ehdfngdfbgf** парсите эту переменную как вам нужно сравнивайте с тем что имеете и делайте с ней все что душе угодно)

Answer (score -2):

Советую такие вещи делать через .htaccess (mod_rewrite)

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^page/(.*)?$ page.php?query=$1 [L]
```

Ну и уже в page.php

```
echo $_GET['query']; // что ввел пользователь
```